# Is it possible to open a socket using HTML/jQuery on port 23?

Tags: php, jquery, html, sockets, web-applications

I'm trying to listen to data being pushed out on port 23 (I can't change it) of a specific IP address and listening to it using jQuery or HTML.

Now, I've managed to get it working using PHP and AJAX using a crude implementation. This isn't persistent and will time out as soon as the PHP script times out while listening.  I would prefer a solution that allowed my web application to directly listen to the data coming from this.

Previous attempts using HTML websockets result in a security error, saying that port 23 is not a allowed port. Any suggestions as to how to go about this?

Comment: Do you want to have the data directly on the client or would it be acceptable to have it on the server and let the client pull them from there (or push them down using websockets, etc..)

Comment: Will you be using a shared server or do you have access to a dedicated server? If the latter, I expect you could just set up a proxy (e.g. in Apache or PHP) that recreates your web socket on a normal port.

Comment: @ Rangad      

Either works, currently the datasource is being pushed down port 23 on a local IP. I can read it and use it with a PHP / AJAX combination - it woudl be more ideal to initialize a listener and directly into a jquery/java array in the Webapp as the data is pushed to avoid PHP timeouts.

@ Halfer 

It's a Shared Server - the data is coming from a IP on the local network

Comment: (On Stack Exchange comments, please use separate comments for each at-username, and don't put a space between the at-symbol and the username. Type the symbol, then start typing the user-name -- you'll get an autocomplete menu. If you don't type them correctly, users won't get a notification message).

Comment: @Rangad: see the OP's message above.

Comment: Do you have another server at your disposal that can be used as a proxy? Not saying it's the only way to fix it, but it sounds like it should work, and it'd be quick to try. A cheap VPS would do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting around this by using node.js to create a persistent server that would just communicate with the device and act as a relay for the web application i'm building.